# Image is not displaying in phone gap?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am first designing the UI using Sencha Touch 2.0 There i am putting one image in the panel. But when i running using phonegap, the image is not displaying. Here is the code for the image:

```
 xtype: 'image',
            docked: 'left',
            height: 130,
            width: 170,
            src: 'images/logo.png'
```

this images folder is app folder. Inside app folder i kept the view and models also.

I am tried in many way. But not able to resolve this issue..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you tried changing src to `app/images/logo.png` yet?

Comment: @Thiem Nguyen It is working..How can i make it resolved..

Comment: This question dude..how can i make your reply as the answer for the question???

Comment: I've just posted it as an answer. Thanks for your remind.

Comment: I should say thanks..hope you help me later also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried changing `src` to `app/images/logo.png`. It might solve your problem.